# Unit Tests not discovered and executed in Visual Studio 2017 when legacy test settings specified

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2017

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Professional 15.4.5 and I found out unit tests will not be discovered when legacy `.testsettings` is loaded via selecting it in the `Test > Test Settings > Select Test Settings` menu

Here are steps to reproduce it:

1. Create a new Solution
2. Create a `Class Library` project with target framework `.NET Framework 4.5.2` with following simple class:

   ```
   public class Class1
   {
       public bool True => true;
   }
   ```
3. Create a `Unit Test Project(.Net Framework)` with target framework `.NET Framework 4.5.2` and setup project reference and write a simple test:

   ```
   [TestClass]
   public class UnitTest1
   {
       [TestMethod]
       public void TestMethod1()
       {
           Assert.IsTrue(new Class1().True);
       }
   }
   ```
4. Run the test, the test should be discovered and run
5. Use solution context menu to select `Add > New Item`, select `Test Settings` in the left pane and select `Test Settings` in the middle to create a new test settings.
6. Skip the setting by just closing the dialog. Set the test settings by clicking the menu `Test > Test Settings > Select Test Settings`
7. Run the test again, it was not executed and some information can be seen in the Output pane:

> [2017/12/08 13:36:20 Informational] ------ Run test started ------
>
> [2017/12/08 13:36:22 Warning] Warning : A testsettings file or a runsettings with a ForcedLegacyMode set to true is not supported with the MSTest V2 Adapter.
>
> [2017/12/08 13:36:22 Error] Test adapter sent back a result for an unknown test case. Ignoring result for 'TestMethod1'.
>
> [2017/12/08 13:36:22 Informational] ========== Run test finished: 0 run (0:00:01.9851985) ==========

### Updates

To answer @aruna I followed my own instructions again with VS2017 Professional 15.5.7

The test still failed to run but the output is different:

> [2018/03/01 13:39:13 Informational] ------ Load Playlist started ------
>
> [2018/03/01 13:39:13 Informational] ========== Load Playlist finished (0:00:00.001) ==========
>
> [2018/03/01 13:40:46 Informational] ------ Discover test started ------
>
> [2018/03/01 13:40:48 Informational] ========== Discover test finished: 1 found (0:00:02.1855628) ==========
>
> [2018/03/01 13:40:48 Informational] ------ Run test started ------
>
> [2018/03/01 13:40:49 Informational] ========== Run test finished: 1 run (0:00:01.5406918) ==========
>
> [2018/03/01 13:41:32 Informational] ------ Run test started ------
>
> [2018/03/01 13:41:34 Warning] Warning : A testsettings file or a runsettings with a ForcedLegacyMode set to true is not supported with the MSTest V2 Adapter.
>
> [2018/03/01 13:41:34 Warning] No test is available in D:\git\demo\unit-test-legacy-settings\UnitTestProject1\bin\Debug\UnitTestProject1.dll. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.
>
> [2018/03/01 13:41:34 Informational] ========== Run test finished: 0 run (0:00:02.0727927) ==========

Comment: Did you fix this issue?

Comment: @Aruna please see my updated post

Comment: I got it fixed by changing the DLL reference

Comment: @Aruna could u elaborate?

Comment: I got the exact same... But only in a branch, not the main trunk :(

Comment: @JPChapleau is it a public repo? maybe we could investigate together

Comment: Thanks @LukeFan but it is a private one. We figure out that we had to delete our load tests AND delete the project. Leading us to believe there  is "something" hidden to TFS that can get jacked up. VS bug?

Comment: @JPChapleau in my case I don't have anything to do with TFS so maybe it's a VS bug. Hope someone else has got answers though

Comment: I am also having this issue, but in my case, the tests are not even being discovered, if I remove testsetting file everything works fine and if I add it, tests are not even discovered. @Aruna how did you fix it?